# Why getsockopt() does not return the expected value for TCP_MAXSEG?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I'm trying **configuring programmatically** the **MSS** of my TCP connection on a GNU/Linux system, specifically **Ubuntu 12.04, kernel 3.2.0-68-generic**

According to *man 7 tcp*

> TCP_MAXSEG The maximum segment size for outgoing TCP packets.  If this
>   option is  set  before  connection establishment, it also changes the
>   MSS value announced to the other end in the initial packet.Values
>   greater than the (eventual) interface MTU have no effect.  TCP  will 
>   also  impose  its minimum and maximum bounds over the value provided.

this let me think I can configure the value *before* I connect the TCP socket.
I wrote a small chunk of code to create a socket and I used setsockopt() to configure the MSS.
In my test I'm setting the mss to 1000B.

The code calls setsockopt() followed by getsockopt() to double check the value has been properly configured. Both syscalls return 0 (no error). After that I connect to a remote host to verify via tcpdump the used mss is correct. Here what I see:

- returned MSS value from getsockopt() is always 536 Byte
- tcpdump shows the configured MSS in the syn packet

Modified my code to configure the MSS *after* I connect the socket.

- returned MSS value from getsockopt() is 1448 Bye

Is there a correct way to explain such behavior?

A couple of notes:

- according to wikipedia 536 B = MaxIPDatagramSize - IPHeaderSize - TcpHeaderSize
  this is to avoid IP packet fragmentation.
- creating a socket and connecting it (no setsockopt() call), displays an mss of 536 B returned by getsockopt() but tcpdump shows an announced mss of 1460 B in the SYN packet, that makes sense being 1500 - IpHeader - TcpHeader

Below, if you are interested, is my code:

```
int setSocketMss( int i_sd, int i_mss )
{
    int res = 0;
    int mss = i_mss;
    socklen_t len = sizeof( mss );

    res = ::setsockopt( i_sd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_MAXSEG, &mss, len );
    if ( res < 0 )
    {
        qDebug() << "error: cannot configure mss for socket" << i_sd;
        return -1;
    }
    res = ::getsockopt( i_sd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_MAXSEG, &mss, &len );
    if ( mss != i_mss )
    {
        qDebug() << "MSS set to" << i_mss << "but read value is" << mss;
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "MSS for socket" << i_sd << " has been set to" << mss;
    }
    return mss;
}

void configureAddrStruct( const QString & i_ipAddress,
                          quint16 i_port,
                          struct sockaddr_in & o_sockaddr )
{
    o_sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl( QHostAddress(i_ipAddress).toIPv4Address() );
    o_sockaddr.sin_port = htons( i_port );
    o_sockaddr.sin_family = PF_INET;
    memset( o_sockaddr.sin_zero, 0, sizeof(o_sockaddr.sin_zero) );
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sd = ::socket( PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, getprotobyname("tcp")->p_proto );
    if ( -1 == sd )
    {
        qDebug() << "erro creating socket";
        exit (1);
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "created socket:" << sd;
    }

    setSocketMss( sd, 1000 );

    struct sockaddr_in localAddress;
    struct sockaddr_in remoteAddress;

    configureAddrStruct( "192.168.23.7", 0, localAddress );
    configureAddrStruct( "192.168.23.176", 9999, remoteAddress );

    int res = ::bind( sd,
                      reinterpret_cast<const sockaddr *>( &localAddress ),
                      sizeof(localAddress) );
    if ( -1 == res )
    {
        qDebug() << "error binding socket to local address";
        exit(2);
    }

    //setSocketMss( sd, 1000 );

    res = ::connect( sd,
                     reinterpret_cast<const sockaddr*>( &remoteAddress ),
                     sizeof(remoteAddress) );
    if ( -1 == res )
    {
        qDebug() << "error connecting to remote host";
        ::perror( "connect()" );
        exit(2);
    }

    //setSocketMss( sd, 1000 );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now the patch was accepted by Linux netdev. https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/netdev/net.git/commit/?id=34dfde4ad87b BTW, the 'CLOSE' state means `TCP_CLOSE` state in Linux kernel, and new socket will be initialized with the state. I'm not sure if the patch would be backported to previous stable versions. *** Original answer: It's probably a bug. I sent a patch, it may fix it. [tcp: Return user_mss for TCP_MAXSEG in CLOSE/LISTEN state if user_mss set](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/netdevbpf/patch/20230524083350.54197-1-cambda@linux.alibaba.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing the wrong thing. You should send the socket receive buffer size, at the receiver.

Comment: sorry, but I'm not sure I understood your answer, could you please expand it?

Comment: I could, but why? I've given you enough relevant information for you to solve the problem.