# TCP socket server c++/c window size

Tags: c++, c, http, tcp, raspbian

I created a small c++/c http socket server on raspberry pi. In past I have only sent/receive 1460 data bytes at a time. Although recently I have become aware that I can send more than this. I would like to send data from server to client as fast as possible. Coulda I obtain the window size (max segment size) the client can handle so that I could send that amount of data. Say if it were 8192, then I would like to transmit that amount on each server socket send. Can any give me some pointers on how to do this?

Comment: Just send as much as you can on every `send()`. You don't need to know the window size for that. TCP will take care of the details. Use a large application buffer, say 32k or more.

Comment: Agree with @EJP - the client requests the size of buffer they want to receive - the socket communications decide what gets passed and when

Answer (score 0):

Use getsockopt with TCP_MAXSEG:

```
int mss;
socklen_t len = sizeof mss;
getsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_MAXSEG, &mss, &len);
```

From `man tcp`:

> ```
>   TCP_MAXSEG
>          The maximum segment size for outgoing TCP packets.  In Linux 2.2
>          and  earlier,  and  in Linux 2.6.28 and later, if this option is
>          set before connection establishment, it  also  changes  the  MSS
>          value  announced to the other end in the initial packet.  Values
>          greater than the (eventual) interface MTU have no  effect.   TCP
>          will  also  impose its minimum and maximum bounds over the value
>          provided.
> ```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996741/why-getsockopt-does-not-return-the-expected-value-for-tcp-maxseg), this should be done *after* the connection is established, otherwise a generic default value will be returned.